# Storing and retrieving constants in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have just started playing with laravel haveing come from codeigniter and I am trying to work out the best way to define a series of constants.
CI uses a constants folder under app/config and I was largely happy with this approach for most things but wanted advice as to the best way to do this in Laravel.

My constants fall into 3 categories and I would like advice if possible on how best to store and retrieve each (baring in mind I'm completely new to Laravel.

**Type 1**:
Constants which need to be loaded everytime a controller is called:
e.g. I would like to start by defining a constant to tell me if the user is requesting content via ajax, this is what I used to do in CI constants file:
`define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')`

**Type 2**:
Constants which can be changed by the user:
Are these best stored in a database or would writing to a config file be a better option? Again looking for advice on how to store and retrieve

**Type 3**:
Constants which are only needed in specific controllers:
Ideally I would like to be able to group constants into arrays or separate files and pull them out in groups as required.
e.g. I could just retrieve my upload settings for my upload controller.

Thanks for any help/advice in advance - examples would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Type 1**
You can add any constant in Bundle (or application) start.php file.

**Type 2 and 3**
I would suggest using Config for both these requirement.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is create a file inside app/config folder called "constants.php" 
app/config/constants.php

The code inside is in array way.

"some value",
    'c2'=>"some value"
    );
?>

then inside each controller you can retrieve using 
Config::get('constants.c1');

I think is an easy way to do it, it's more scalable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//file : app/config/constants.php

return [
    'IS_AJAX' => isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']
];
```

in anywhere:

```
echo Config::get('constants.IS_AJAX');
```